# GDPR data deletion: can I ask the company to delete the data it had exported in the United States?

Tags: gdpr, data-protection, data-storage, data

I am located in Italy.

I have subscribed to a service and provided some PII that "could be exported in the United States".

If I send a GDPR request to delete my data, can I ask them to also delete they data that they are storing aboard in the United States?

Thank you very much